# Angular changing the text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where a user checks a checkbox and saves it, it will say Approved next to it. But when the checkbox is not checked and the user saves it, the text will be Not Approved (when IsApproved is false). How can I achieve this? It currently just says Approved for both scenarios.

[image]

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="IsApproved">
                                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ürün Onay Durumu </th>
                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                                        <mat-checkbox
                                            (click)="EditIndexProduct != i ? $event.preventDefault() : $event.stopPropagation()"
                                            [(ngModel)]="row.IsApproved" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                                            Approved
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </td>
                                </ng-container>
```

Comment: You have a hard coded 'Approved' text inside the mat-checkbox. Print it based on the IsApproved flag accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="EditIndexProduct != i ? $event.preventDefault() : $event.stopPropagation()" [(ngModel)]="row.IsApproved" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    {{row.IsApproved === true ? 'Approved' : 'Not Approved'}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-izfcsd?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html